# opencv, selective coloring effect

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors

I want to make an effect on an image, such that specific color remains same, and the rest becomes grayscale. However, the output of my program is quite bad, could anyone please help me to improve my code? It breaks when the coordinates exceed 500, and the color range shown is too small. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
int i1=10, i2=50, a = 10;// coordinates of pixel value, whose color must remain; hue range

IplImage* GetNewImage(IplImage* frame, IplImage* imgHSV){
    IplImage* imgNew = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    IplImage* imgBW = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    CvScalar s1;
    CvScalar s2;
    CvScalar s3;
    s3 = cvGet2D(imgHSV, i1, i2);

    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(s3.val[0] - 10, s3.val[1] - 50, s3.val[2] - 50), cvScalar(s3.val[0] + 10, s3.val[1] + 50, s3.val[2] + 50), imgBW);

    imgNew = cvCloneImage(frame);


    for (int i = 0; i < frame->height; i++) for (int j = 0; j < frame->width; j++) {
        s1 = cvGet2D(imgBW, i, j);
        s2 = cvGet2D(imgNew, i, j);
        if (s1.val[0] == 0){

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                 s3.val[k] = (s2.val[0] * 0.114 + s2.val[1] * 0.587 + s2.val[2] * 0.299);//converting to grayscale
                     cvSet2D(imgNew, i, j, s3);
            }

        }


    }
    cvReleaseImage(&imgBW);
    return imgNew;
}
```

Comment: Site-note: try to use the new OpenCV API instead.

Answer (score 1):

- drop that outdated c-api, it's dead & gone.
- you already found out about inRange(), use the outcome as a mask for further processing
- there's cvtColor(src,dst,CV_BGR2GRAY) already, prefer the builtin stuff to rolling your own
- opencv is a computer-vision / ml library, you're abusing it as a 2nd class photoshop. - don't !

Comment: most of the opencv source is C. It is not dead. It is not gone. ANd you won’t be able to read the source code if you drop and forget it.

Comment: I agree with Berak. +1 for that!

Comment: Vlad, the c-api is no more developed. you can't use anything added after 2010 from it. any contribution to opencv using it will get rejected. i call that - dead. i think it's more of an specific SO problem, this is sometimes a huge vault of outdated stuff.

Comment: @Vlad, btw, most of the c-api calls nowadays are only shallow wrappers to c++ api calls ..

Comment: If you unwrap it completely you will be staring on a lot of C functions. At least in improc module. And tons of examples are still c. There are two folders c and cpp in samples (at least in 2.4.0.2 version). Overall, if some function can be written in a simple way, why not use C? However, if you work on a big project with many collaborators, C++ is a solution.